# Find most common multi words in an input file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

Say I have a text file, I can find the most frequent words easily using Counter. However, I would also like to find multi words like "tax year, fly fishing, u.s. capitol, etc.". Words that occur together the most.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('full.txt') as f:
    passage = f.read()

words = re.findall(r'\w+', passage)

cap_words = [word for word in words]

word_counts = Counter(cap_words)

for k, v in word_counts.most_common():
    print(k, v)
```

I have this currently, however, this only find one word. How do I find multiple words?

Comment: `[word for word in words]` does nothing; `words` is already a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is a way to count **bigrams** (strings containing two words).

The **nltk** library is great for doing lots of language related tasks, and you can use **Counter** from **collections** for all your counting-related activities!

```
import nltk
from nltk import bigrams
from collections import Counter

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(passage)
print(Counter(bigrams(tokens))
```

Comment: Thank you! but I keep getting "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" for line 7 for the "for".

Comment: I simplified the answer, let me know how it works out!

Comment: This works great! I will accept this answer when it allows me.

Answer (score 0):

What you call mutliwords (there is no such thing) is actually called bigrams. You can get a list of bigrams from a list of words by zipping it with itself with a displacement:

```
bigrams = [f"{x} {y}" for x,y, in zip(words, words[1:])]
```

P.S. NLTK would be indeed a better tool to get bigrams.